# How to Rebuild Sitecore Index without blowing my log files?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7.5

I have the Sitecore + Coveo system. I have automated Rebuild/Refresh Index using command. But while performing Rebuild/Refresh my Logging files are going up to ~40GB.

Is there anyway so that I can restrict logging while Rebuild/Refresh?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set the logging level for your Crawling log. In the `web.config` file, find the logger called `Sitecore.Diagnostics.Crawling` and set the log level.

This is mine, set to `INFO`

```
<logger name="Sitecore.Diagnostics.Crawling" additivity="false">
  <level value="INFO" />
  <appender-ref ref="CrawlingLogFileAppender" />
</logger>
```

That should reduce the amount of logs written.  If you want to reduce it even further, you can set it to `ERROR` or `NONE`, but I would not recommend `NONE`.

Comment: Does this setting affect the main log.****.txt? I though this setting will affect the CrawlingLogFile.***.txt. I'm facing the issue with the main log.****.txt not with the CrawlingLogFile.***.txt.

Comment: I wouldn't expect your regular log file to get that big unless there were lots of exceptions being logged.  The best way to deal with that is to fix the errors.

Comment: There are different loggers that wrote to different files. They each have their own level settings.

Comment: Thanks @RichardHauer, I had priority set to Debug in my Log4net/Root settings.